# Unable to Select from a Auto complete List using Watir

Tags: ruby, watir

**My HTML is as below:**

```
<div class="input-group">
<div class="ux-autocomplete">
<input type="text" placeholder="" class="search-input typeahead" autocomplete="off" readonly=""> 
<input type="text" tabindex="" name="query" placeholder="Search" class="search-input typeahead-input" autocomplete="off" aria-autocomplete="both"> 
    <div class="autocomplete-suggestive-text active ">
        <ul class="container">  
            <li><a href="#" class=" "><span>ipho</span>ne plans</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class=" "><span>ipho</span>ne 6 plans</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class=" "><span>ipho</span>ne 5s</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class=" "><span>ipho</span>ne 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class=" "><span>ipho</span>ne 6+</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
<input type="submit" class="button radius ico ico-only ico-search btn-submit" title="Search" value="Search">
```

**Please Help out how to select the 2nd Item from the List.**
I have put the list html in the comment below.

Comment: It's a auto suggestion drop down menu. When i write "Ipho", the above options gets displayed. The list html is ----          <li><a href="#" class=" "><span>ipho</span>ne plans</a></li>

Comment: Instead of adding a comment, you should edit your question to include the (preferably formatted) HTML and what you've tried to solve the problem.  For example, do you get an error with `b.link(text: "iphone 6 plans").click`?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to open it by Chrome Developer Tool

And See the final html it is after completing the auto-list

Sometimes the item you see on the screen is not what you see in HTML file

Since it might create it's own item on run time